# How do I restrict an application from phoning home?

Tags: windows-7, security-policy

I have an application running on Windows 7 that I would like to continue using but prevent it from accessing the Internet. How do I do this? Do I use some kind of local policy, etc?

The app would sometime phone home and I need to stop this but continue using the app.

Answer (score 2):

More of an SU question but here's the answer:

Windows 7 includes an application-level firewall which you can use to restrict network traffic on a per-program basis.

To do this:

- Go to Start -> Control Panel -> Firewall
- Pick 'Advanced Settings' on the left bar
- Click 'Outbound Rules' on the left, then 'New Rule' on the right
- Select 'Program', Next
- Browse to the program's .exe, Next
- Select 'Block the connection', Next
- Leave all the boxes ticked, Next
- Give the rule a name, Finish

Job done ;)

Comment: I'm new here, what's SU?

Comment: I just followed your instructions. Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to make a firewall rule for every program, use this plug in for the Vista/W7 firewall, its an outbound active firewall.

I use the free version

http://www.sphinx-soft.com/Vista/order.html?from=Windows7FirewallControlx64

.